# Read Bluetooth on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to read data from Bluetooth device, first I installed "S2 Bluetooth term3" which works very nice..

Now I'm trying to read data from my own application creating a socket so:

```
mSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
```

But, doesn't work, I got this:

**Service discovery failed**

I've read several posts and I've tried this:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
mSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

And I got this:

**Permission denied**

This fails on this line:

> mSocket.connect();

**The UUID of my device is**: 00000111-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34bf

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, since Android 4.0.4 (API 10) is necessary to use:

```
createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(...)
```

instead of:

```
createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(...)
```

**Now my app works!**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the proper permissions in the manifest?

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />`
```

Comment: Perhaps the same issue!? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520575/android-4-0-bluetooth-connection-error-to-an-embedded-device-permission-denie]

Comment: I've readed and I found that my application works fine in Android 2.3.6 but no on Android 4.0+

Now, I've readed and I've tried show the popup authorization to enable bluetooth, but I have the same error. Any idea?